# "close all" equivalent for HeatMap plots

Tags: matlab, heatmap

If you create a bunch of heatmaps:

```
for i=1:10
    HeatMap(rand(5,5))
end
```

then you're left with a bunch of open figure windows. Although they're not exactly "Figure" windows, they're "HeatMap" windows (tangential question: why???).

If you have a bunch of normal figures open, you can close them all by typing `close all`. But this does nothing to HeatMap windows. So... what's the alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can close figures with hidden handles (I believe it's the case for HeatMap) with

```
close all hidden
```

You can also force closing all figures with

```
close all force
```

See [CLOSE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/close.html) documentation for more details.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. In 10 years there will probably be something like `close all force everything allofthem yesthatonetoo`.

Answer (score 1):

They are [objects](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/bioinfo/ref/heatmap.html). I would advice the following - store the references beforehand.

```
H = {};
for i=1:10
    H{i} = HeatMap(rand(5,5))
end
%Now delete all!
cellfun(@delete,H);
```

Comment: So this means that if I create the heatmap in some nested function somewhere, I need to be passing around all these `HeatMap` objects all the time? Or is there something more equivalent to `close all`?